# Derivatives question help

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, optimization

The question is :Find the derivative of $f(x)=e^c + c^x$. Assume that c is a constant.

Wouldn't $f'(x)=   ce^{c-1} + xc^{x-1}$.    It keeps saying this answer is incorrect, What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Since $c$ is constant, then $e^c$ is also a constant.  What is the derivative of a constant?  Furthermore, $c^x$ is an exponential function, so the power rule doesn't apply.

Comment: So would e^c disappear? Because a derivative of a constant is just 0. Which would leave me with just ce^(c-1)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$f(x)=e^{c}+c^{x}$$ where $c$ is a constant. We know that since $c$ is a constant, $e^c$ is also a constant making ${d\over dx}(e^c)=0$. Also, ${d\over dx}(c^x)=c^x\ln c$. The reason for this is because ${d\over dx}(c^x)={d\over dx}{(e^{\ln c})^x}={d\over dx}({e^{{(\ln c}){x}})}=e^{({\ln c)} x}\cdot {d\over dx} {(\ln c)}x=(e^{\ln c})^x\cdot (\ln c)=c^x\ln c$. Thus $$f'(x)={c^x\ln c}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, $e^c$ is a constant, so its derivative is zero. As for the second term, $c^x$, the rule for the derivative of a variables as an exponents is better understood if you write the function as

$c^x = e^{x \ln{c}}$

So, clearly the derivative is equal to $c^x\ln{c} $

To sum up, $f'(x) = c^x \ln{c}$

Answer (score 0):

There are distinct derivation rules for two cases:

- A variable raised to a constant
- A constant raised to a variable.

You tried to apply the first case to the second term, $c^x$, where you really want the second case. Consider the general rule for constants raised to variables, $$ \frac{d}{dx} (a^u) = a^u \ln a \frac{du}{dx}. $$

Regarding the first term $e^c$, perhaps you missed that $e$ is a mathematical constant: the base of the natural logarithm, approximately equal to 2.71828.

Answer (score 0):

Since "c" is a constant,the derivative of the first term is zero and then the derivative of f(x) is the same as the derivative of g(x)=c^x. I suggest you go through loagrithms and re-express g(x) in a more familiar form. Are you able to continue with this ?